# Can't map over a query in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Im using Apollo with React to map over a query but get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I don't know if the passing of props is the problem or the query it self...

I know that the Query is in made of fragments but changing that dose not fix the error.

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import { gql } from  'apollo-boost'

import ListPosts from './components/ListPosts'

function App() {
  return (
    <Query query={GET_POSTS_QUERY}>
      {(data, loading, error) => {
        if (loading) return <div>loading</div>
        if (error) return <div>error</div>

        return <ListPosts posts={data.allPosts} />

      }}
    </Query>
  )
}

const GET_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
{
  allPosts {
    ... on PostType {
      title
      createdAt
      content
      postImage
      postedBy {
        username
      }
    }
    ... on Post2Type {
      title
      createdAt
      content
      postImage
      postedBy {
        username
      }
    }
  }
}

`

export default App;
```

**ListPosts.js**

```
import React from "react";

const ListPosts = ({ posts }) => (
    <div>
        {posts.map(post => (
            <div key={post.id}>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)

export default ListPosts;
```

For more context here is the response in JSON

```
{
  "data": {
    "allPosts": [
      {
        "title": "vesti",
        "createdAt": "2020-04-05T12:37:09.451520+00:00",
        "content": "<p><strong>asdasda</strong></p>",
        "postImage": "post/logo.png",
        "postedBy": {
          "username": "filip"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "asds",
        "createdAt": "2020-04-05T17:44:11.291829+00:00",
        "content": "<p>asdasd</p>",
        "postImage": "",
        "postedBy": {
          "username": "filip"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: `posts` prop is undefined in `ListPosts.js`. Have you `console.log`'d or dropped a `debugger` there to examine what the value is when rendering? Done the same in `App.js` to look at `data`?

Comment: @DrewReese I get `data: undefined` which doesn't make sense, to me, because i get a 
normal response in graphql. First i thought it has something to do with CORS but it's not. Is there something else that you can think of that might cause the data to be undefined?

Comment: Just bad syntax - read apollo `<Query/>` component usage docs - v. 2.5 !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Query` [Render prop function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-components/#render-prop-function)

> The render prop function that you pass to the `children` prop of `Query`
>   is called with an object (`QueryResult`) that has the following
>   properties. This object contains your query result, plus some helpful
>   functions for refetching, dynamic polling, and pagination.

In other words, the render prop is a props object with the properties you need. The component is also only passed a single argument.

The entire `props` was being assigned to a variable named `data`, and because `loading` and `error` are undefined, i.e. falsey, those conditional tests fail and you try to render the posts. Now, `data.allPosts` or really `props.allPosts` doesn't exist.

Using object destructuring you can access the `data`, `loading`, and `error` props.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Query query={GET_POSTS_QUERY}>
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>loading</div>
        if (error) return <div>error</div>

        return <ListPosts posts={data.allPosts} />

      }}
    </Query>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. your response in JSON isn't the full JSON should be this:**

```
{
  data: {
    allPosts: [
      {
        title: "vesti",
        createdAt: "2020-04-05T12:37:09.451520+00:00",
        content: "<p><strong>asdasda</strong></p>",
        postImage: "post/logo.png",
        postedBy: {
          username: "filip"
        }
      },
      {
        title: "asds",
        createdAt: "2020-04-05T17:44:11.291829+00:00",
        content: "<p>asdasd</p>",
        postImage: "",
        postedBy: {
          username: "filip"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**2. You are sending your data.allpost which shouldn't be camel case so when you receive it as a prop in ListPost you shouldn't wrap it in an object should be:**

```
const ListPosts = (posts) => (...)
```

**3. If you want to map the object you will have to access the array within the object by Object.entries() or Object.values() so:**

```
Object.entries(posts).map(postArray => (...)
```

will return [posts:, [array(2)]]

**4. Now that you have access to the array you will need to map it like you have:**

```
 postArray[1].map(post => {
 return(
  <div key={post.title}>
          <div style={{ borderStyle: "solid" }}>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          </div>
          <div style={{ borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: "2px" }}>
            <p>{post.createdAt}</p>
            <p>{post.content}</p>
            <p>{post.postImage}</p>
            <p>{post.postedBy.username}</p>
          </div>
  </div>
  )}
```

I've created an example of this for you for better understanding here: https://codesandbox.io/s/component-drilling-props-grxm4

**Check the console you will be able to see the logs**

hope this helps you goodluck!

Comment: What is full JSON? OP has valid JSON syntax. Object keys can be cased however you want. This answer doesn't address why the `allPosts` data was undefined to begin with.

Comment: @DrewReese it's undefined because it is wrapped {posts} so it is returning undefined

Comment: That is how `props` and object destructuring work, my friend. `ListPosts = props => {...` is to `props.posts` as `ListPosts = ({ posts }) => {...` is to `posts`. Like I said though, your answer doesn't address why the value that was passed to the `posts` prop was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";

const ListPosts = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.posts.map(post => {
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          </div>
        });
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListPosts;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
import React from "react";

const ListPosts = props => (
<div>
    {props.posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.id}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
)

export default ListPosts;
```

can you do these changes?

Comment: How is this different than OP's code, other than removal of object destructuring?